# PostgreSQL: Getting date associated with max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in the form of

```
USER  |VALUE |DATE
-------------------------
user1 | 1337 | 2019-11-01
user1 | 1338 | 2019-03-28
user2 | 1234 | 2019-04-23
user2 | 4567 | 2019-05-05
```

and want to get the maximum value of every user with the associated date. When I do something like

```
SELECT max(VALUE) FROM table
GROUP BY USER
```

I have the problem that I can neither aggregate nor group by the DATE. How can I tell PostgreSQL that I just wanna have the date associated with the row where the max. value is?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=057fa9670554b8cca4b8cc62403b526a)

You can use `DISTINCT ON`: This gives you the first record of an ordered group. In your case the groups is your `user` column. This you have to order by `value DESC` to get the max `value` to be the first record. This will be taken - including the associated `date` value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user)
    *
FROM 
    mytable
ORDER BY user, value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want other aggregations in the query, you can also use `array_agg()` to mimic a "first" function:

```
select user, max(value), count(*),
       (array_agg(date order by value desc))[1] as date_at_max
from t
group by user;
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with DISTINCT ON

Comment: @gizarmaluke . . . `distinct on` is the best solution to the particular question you asked.  I offered this as an alternative if you had simplified the question.